# onnxruntime-web A tensor's dims must be a number array

Tags: javascript, tensor, codesandbox, onnxruntime

I want to replicate [this working MNIST inference example](https://codesandbox.io/s/pytorch-to-javascript-with-onnx-vgzep) which uses the deprecated [onnxjs](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxjs) library in favor of using the new [onnxruntime](https://onnxruntime.ai), but I'm getting an error while creating a Tensor from the canvas image:

```js
const imgData = this.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.CANVAS_SIZE, this.CANVAS_SIZE);
let img_arr= new Float32Array(imgData.data); //560 x 560 = 313600
const dims = [1, 1, 560, 560];
const input = new ort.Tensor(img_arr, "float32", dims);
```

**Error Message:**

```
A tensor's dims must be a number array
```

The full code to replicate my problem is available in [this repository](https://github.com/bhomaidan1990/onnx_vue).

I have tried also to replicate my problem on Code sandbox, but it seems that the code sandbox has an issue installing the `onnxruntime-web`: `Unable to open 'ort-web.min.js': File not found (file:///sandbox/node_modules/onnxruntime-web/dist/ort-web.min.js).`

So I get another error: `invalid wire type 4 at offset 3`

[image: Edit 50069724/how-to-add-multiple-material-ui-palette-colors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convention (parameters order) of Tensor creation has changed in the [new API](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-inference-examples/blob/main/js/api-usage_tensor/tensor-create.js#L15):

```js
const input = new ort.Tensor("float32", img_arr, dims);
```